# I found a pattern in consecutive squares: $(a^2-b^2)-(b^2-c^2)$ is always $2$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

I was working on squares of numbers then found out that the difference of difference between two consecutive numbers is $2$. Saying this with an example like

$$2^2=4\qquad\qquad 3^2=9\qquad\qquad 4^2=16$$

$$9-4=5\qquad\qquad 16-9=7$$

$$7-5=2$$

$4^2-3^2-(3^2-2^2)$ is always $2$. If we take any three consecutive three numbers and do the same thing we get $2$. Is this proved before ?

Comment: Yes, this was known to the Babylonians and was probably known in prehistory.

Comment: Just simplify $((n + 1)^2 - n^2) - (n^2 - (n - 1)^2)$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Equivalently, the squares are the cumulative sums of the odd numbers. $1+3+5+7+\dots$

Comment: Try it with four consecutive cubes, you'll always get six. Generalize.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE ... and congratulations on your discovery! You have tapped into an interesting notion called "[finite differences](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FiniteDifference.html)". While it happens to be known, the fact that someone found it before you is merely an *accident of time*; it does not diminish your personal accomplishment. Keep at it!

Answer (score 2):

This is a nice discovery! But why does it work?
Let $n^2$ and $(n+1)^2$ be two consecutive squares.
If you expand $(n+1)^2$, you will get $n^2+2n+1$.
$(n^2+2n+1)-(n^2)=2n+1$.
This means the difference between consecutive squares is always the odd numbers.
Now, we can say that $((n+2)^2-(n+1)^2)-((n+1)^2-n^2)=(2(n+1)+1)-(2n+1)=2$.

Q.E.D.